# Help in writing SQL query for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables with following structures:-

1)  Student_Details:-

```
studentId(pk)
studentName
studentGrade
studentExamStatus
```

2) Student_Result:-

```
studentId(fk)
studentRank
```

The data is inserted in 2nd table only if `studentExamStatus` is `P`, otherwise if the `studentExamStatus` is `F` there is no record in 2nd table for that student.

I want to write query that will give me all the details of all the students along with rank and if there is no rank blank data or null value is fetched.

I tried with normal join but its only giving me students with rank and not all the students

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT sd.*, sr.StudentRank
FROM Student_Details as SD
LEFT OUTER JOIN Student_Result as SR
    ON sd.StudentID = Sr.StudentID
```

Any student without a record in Student_Result will return `NULL` for `StudentRank`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at how you can use [outer joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518.aspx).